# How to use ActiveRecord for multiply join same table (ruby on rails)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My application for learning words by reading sentences and translation of these sentences.

Each word has and belongs to many sentences and each sentence has translated sentences ('links' table) but not all translations for specific language (many english sentences are translated into japanese but do not have a translation into Russian)

I need to get words (english for example) that have sentences (english) that have translated sentences (russian)

DB:

```
       words                 sentences_words            sentences              links(sentences_sentences)
_______________________    _____________________    __________________     _____________________________
|id |lang   |word     |    |word_id|sentence_id|    |id|lang|sentence|     |sentence_1_id|sentence_2_id|   
|1  |rus    |Ё        |    |   1   |     1     |    |1 |rus |  ЁЖ    |     |      1      |      5      | 
|2  |rus    |Ж        |    |   1   |     4     |    |2 |rus |  ЗЖ    |     |      1      |      8      | 
|3  |rus    |З        |    |   2   |     1     |    |3 |rus |  ЙЫ    |     |      2      |      6      | 
|4  |rus    |Й        |    |   2   |     2     |    |4 |rus |  ЁЗ    |     |      3      |      7      | 
|5  |rus    |Ы        |    |   3   |     2     |    |5 |eng |  ab    |     |      3      |      10     | 
|6  |eng    |a        |    |   3   |     4     |    |6 |eng |  bc    |     |             |             | 
|7  |eng    |b        |    |   4   |     3     |    |7 |eng |  ca    |     |             |             | 
|8  |eng    |c        |    |   5   |     3     |    |8 |jpn |        |     |             |             | 
|9  |jpn    | ...     |    |   6   |     5     |    |9 |jpn |        |     |             |             | 
|10 |jpn    | ...     |    |   6   |     7     |    |10|jpn |        |     |             |             | 
|   |       |         |    |   7   |     5     |    |11|jpn |        |     |             |             | 
|   |       |         |    |   7   |     6     |    |12|jpn |        |     |             |             | 
|   |       |         |    |   8   |     6     |    |13|jpn |        |     |             |             | 
|   |       |         |    |   8   |     7     |    |14|jpn |        |     |             |             |
```

Models:

```
class Word < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sentences
end

class Sentence < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :words
  has_and_belongs_to_many :translations,
                          class_name: "Sentence",
                          join_table: "links",
                          foreign_key: "sentence_1_id",
                          association_foreign_key: "sentence_2_id"
end
```

This sql works nice but I need activerecord query:

```
sql = "
    select w.word from words w
    join sentences_words sw on sw.word_id = w.id
    join sentences s1 on sw.sentence_id = s1.id
    join links l on l.sentence_1_id = s1.id
    join sentences s2 on l.sentence_2_id = s2.id
    where w.language = 'eng'
    and s1.language = 'eng'
    and s2.language = 'rus'
    group by w.id
    order by w.id"

@words = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

**UPD:**

This code also works:

```
@words = Word.joins("INNER JOIN sentences_words sw ON sw.word_id = words.id
                     INNER JOIN sentences s1 on sw.sentence_id = s1.id
                     INNER JOIN links l on l.sentence_1_id = s1.id
                     INNER JOIN sentences s2 on l.sentence_2_id = s2.id
                     WHERE words.language = 'eng'
                     AND s1.language = 'eng'
                     AND s2.language = 'rus'").group(:id).order(:id)
```

Is it possible to do something like that? (its not works):

```
@words = Word.where(Sentence.where(language: 'eng').joins(:sentences).
where(sentences: {language: 'rus'})).where(language: 'eng')
```

or

```
@words = Word.joins(:sentences).joins(:translations).
where(words: {language: 'eng'}, sentences: {language: 'eng'}, translations: {language: 'rus'}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Rails does have a built in ability to handle a self join in the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @Dmitry you can use the nested join for this . Here is a good link for this [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins]

Comment: Thank you, I need to learn better ))  answer is:  @words = Word.joins(sentences: :translations).where(words: {language: 'eng'}, sentences: {language: 'eng'}, translations_sentences: {language: 'rus'}).group(:id).order(:id)